# e-modifier in javascript? (converting regex from php to js)

Tags: javascript, regex, parameters

I have the following regular expression in PHP

```
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B002JCSBE4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=tv&qid=1264738369&sr=1-1/';
$url=preg_replace(
'/http:\/\/[^>]*?amazon.(.*)\/([^>]*?ASIN|gp\/product|exec\/obidos\/tg\/detail\/-|[^>]*?dp)\/([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})[a-zA-Z0-9#\/\*\-\?\&\%\=\,\._;]*/i',
'http://www.amazon.$1/dp/$3/?tag='.'someone-20',$url );
```

I'm trying to do the same thing, just with javascript.
I can't figure out how to use parameters with something like

```
search = new RegExp(regex);
```

How can I convert this to Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The `/e` modifier is used to execute code. In Javascript, you can do so by passing a function.

For example:

```
preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/e", 
         "'\\1'.strtoupper('\\2').'\\3'", 
         $html_body);
```

becomes

```
html_body.replace(/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/, function(s, x1, x2, x3) {
  return x1 + x2.toUpperCase() + x3;
});
```

in Javascript. (But again, you did not using the `/e` flag in that PHP code.)

Answer (score 0):

You're not not using the `e` modifier in that PHP regex.

The following JavaScript should do the same as your PHP:

```
var url = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B002JCSBE4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=tv&qid=1264738369&sr=1-1/';
var amazon_re = /http:\/\/[^>]*?amazon.(.*)\/([^>]*?ASIN|gp\/product|exec\/obidos\/tg\/detail\/-|[^>]*?dp)\/([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})[a-zA-Z0-9#\/\*\-\?\&\%\=\,\._;]*/i;
url = url.replace(amazon_re, 'http://www.amazon.$1/dp/$3/?tag=someone-20');
```